# VLookup Type of Trigger help

Tags: apex, trigger, custom-object

I have a trigger on Leads that is supposed to work like this: When there is a new and or updated value in the PostalCode field. It is supposed to lookup to a custom object called DMA_Value__c to see if the PostalCode matches one of the values in its Name field. If there is a match it should return another field that is named after the custom object (DMA_Value__c). I'm getting a Method does not exist or incorrect signature at the ischanged() at line 18 column 25. Am I going about this the right way? My trigger is below:

```
trigger PostalCode_Lookup_LEADS on Lead (before insert,before update) {
    Set<String> PostalCode = new Set<String>();
    for(Lead l : trigger.new){
        if(l.PostalCode != null){
            PostalCode.add(l.PostalCode);
        }
    }


    Map<String, DMA_Value__c> validPostalCode = new Map<String, DMA_Value__c>();
    for(DMA_Value__c obj : [SELECT Id, Name, DMA_Value__c FROM DMA_Value__c WHERE Name IN :PostalCode]){
        validPostalCode.put(obj.Name, obj);
    }


    for(Lead l : trigger.new){
        if(l.PostalCode == !ischanged() && validPostalCode.containsKey(l.PostalCode)){
            System.debug(l.PostalCode + ' matched ' + validPostalCode.get(l.PostalCode));
            l.Market_3__c = validPostalCode.get(l.PostalCode).DMA_Value__c;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer came from @ToddSprinkel

```
    trigger UpdateDMA on Lead (before insert, before update) {
//get set of Postal Codes from leads to be inserted or updated
Set<String> postalCodes = new Set<String>();
for(Lead l : trigger.new){
    if(l.PostalCode != null){
        postalCodes.add(l.PostalCode);
    }
}
if(postalCodes.size() > 0){
    //create Map of custom object records with Name (PostalCode) as key
    Map<String,DMA_Value__c> validPostalCode = new Map<String,DMA_Value__c>();
    for(DMA_Value__c obj : [SELECT Id, Name, DMA_Value__c FROM DMA_Value__c WHERE Name IN :postalCodes]){
        validPostalCode.put(obj.Name,obj);
    }
    for(Lead l : trigger.new){
        if((Trigger.isInsert || trigger.oldMap.get(l.Id).PostalCode != l.PostalCode) && validPostalCode.containsKey(l.PostalCode)){
            //not sure what this field is called
            //Market2__c or Market_3__c
            l.Market_3__c = validPostalCode.get(l.PostalCode).DMA_Value__c;
        }
        else if(trigger.oldMap.get(l.Id).PostalCode != l.PostalCode && !validPostalCode.containsKey(l.PostalCode)){
            //blank value if new PostalCode does not match a record in the Map
            l.Market_3__c = null;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

oldMap is what your're looking for.. Something like

```
 if(Trigger.oldMap.get(l.id).PostalCode != l.PostalCode ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
trigger PostalCode_Lookup_LEADS on Lead (before insert,before update) 
 { 
Set PostalCode = new Set(); 

for(Lead l : trigger.new)
{    
    if(l.PostalCode != null)
    { 
        PostalCode.add(l.PostalCode); 
    }
}

Map validPostalCode = new Map(); 
if(PostalCode.size() > 0)
{
    for(DMA_Value__c obj : [SELECT Id, Name, DMA_Value__c FROM DMA_Value__c WHERE Name IN :PostalCode])
    { 
        validPostalCode.put(obj.Name, obj); 
    }
}

for(Lead l : trigger.new)
{ 
    if( (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.oldMap.get(l.Id).PostalCode != l.PostalCode ) && validPostalCode.containsKey(l.PostalCode))
    { 
                System.debug(l.PostalCode + ' matched ' +  validPostalCode.get(l.PostalCode));
        l.Market_3__c = validPostalCode.get(l.PostalCode).DMA_Value__c; 
    }
} 
}
```